# How do I re-add a card that I swiped away from Google Now?

Tags: ios, google-apps, google

I accidentally swiped away the Weather card in Google Now for iOS.

Tapping *Show sample cards* lists the Weather card, but there's no way I can add it again. Under Google Now's settings, it shows that the Weather is *On*, but it's just not there in my Google Now screen.

I've also tried turning off Google Now, and turning it back on. No dice.

[image]

How do I get it back again?

Comment: same thing happened to me, i tried turning them off. it doesnt work.
i swiped apps on my ipad and they disappeared off of my phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: **You have to wait.**

For me, I had swiped away the Weather card at 10 PM, and the next day I got up at 6 AM, I was greeted by the weather forecast for that day.

No refreshing or changing of settings worked, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you can simply **Refresh** the page to restore cards.

Unfortunately, it often isn't that easy. Use the Configuration Gear. You will need to adjust the configuration of the card type that was dismissed (in this case Weather) to restore/refresh the dismissed card data.

Comment: I've tried all that over and over but the card wouldn't appear. What fixed it for me was waiting.